# Android Edit Text with floating label native to lollipop without design support library

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-5.0-lollipop, android-textinputlayout

How can I implement `EditText` with floating label ? I know d**esign support library** supports with some bug. And my app is supporting only versions 5.0 and above. So please tell me how can I do it without using **support library** but using native components.

Comment: There is no native implementation of this. Either using the Design Support Library, or use a third-party library (like [this one](https://github.com/malmstein/FloatingHints) or [this one](https://github.com/marvinlabs/android-floatinglabel-widgets)), or use those libraries as inspiration for writing your own.